# How to block all phone calls, but only allow SMS and networking?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, privacy

It's kinda disturbing when people keep calling me during work or meetings, but to me it's okay if I receive short messages or Whatsapp message because I can reply them few minutes later in a short break. I'm new Android user and wonder if my phone could do that for me.

Comment: Maybe just suppress the ringtone, so you at least know who has tried to call you?

Comment: @Abed maybe there is any app for that but I am able create this tiny apk for you

Comment: @Lumma: if it's useful, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Abed, put here your android version and give me some time

Comment: The  updates solutions: [1](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/108330/96277) and [2](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110479/96277)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tried and tested `Call Barring` method

1. `Go to Settings`
2. Select `Call Settings`
3. Look for `Call barring`
4. Now select `All Incoming`
5. Enter your default PIN (1234)

There, all incoming calls will be blocked. You may still be able to place calls unless you barred that too.

This feature is carrier network dependent and it already exists in the dumbphone era. Still useful though.

Comment: I am unable to find call barring option in Nexus 5. Can you please help. I want to block all incoming call.

Comment: This won't work without proper support from the carrier, as you mentioned. And there are surprisingly many carriers which don't support this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Go to Contact list
2. Select contact
3. Open menu, and press the "Block" button (or "Add to blocklist")

I also found [Call Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartone.callguard) in the Play Store. Maybe you take a look at it.

Comment: You need 50 REP to comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

(At least in some phones, for example LG G3) there's an option for this:

`Settings` / `Networks` / `Call` / (select `Common` if this is dual SIM device) / `Call reject`. You can select `Reject all calls` in `Call reject mode` to reject all calls automatically.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is standard in Android now, should work in all phones. Settings > Call > Call Reject.

Answer (score -1):

Go to call forwarding menu and forward all calls to voicemail

Comment: Not everyone has a voicemail...