# Block all incoming calls

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls, internet

I need to use internet, but without being able to be called. So basically just block all incoming calls.
I used to enable flight mode, but doing so, I'm not able to connect to the internet.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some Samsung devices have a feature called "Blocking Mode", which allows this. You can check if your phone has it from `Phone -> Call settings -> My Device -> Blocking Mode -> Disable incoming calls`.

Answer (score 0):

I found an app based solution for the question. Most of the call blocking apps works by blacklisting the contacts while our goal is to blacklist all of them temporarily. Adding all the contacts in a blacklist can be tiresome and so, an app with whitelist method is much more suitable here. I found and tested the following apps that can do such easily:

1) [Whitelist Call Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tn_software.callblocker&hl=en)

> Whitelist Call Blocker is a call blocker, with that you can determine which callers reach you. So it is possible with activated Whitelist Call Blocker, that for example only the group "family" can reach you. All others only hear a busy signal. Of course, your phone will not ring if the caller is not a member of an allowed group to call you.
>
> By working with groups there are only a few clicks to block or allow hundreds of callers by Whitelist Call Blocker.

2) [Call Block](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.menue.callblocker) -- Run this in Whitelist mode.

> "Call block" is a free full-featured app to block harassing phone calls and SMS for you.
>
> We offer four block modes, the dynamic interface will change automatically, so you can know the current mode easily (block modes available: Block all, Block blacklists only,Accept whitelists only, Accept contacts only)
>   This app also provides answering modes. There are four modes: Power off, Busy, No service, The number is not in service.